# Eigenvalues and bases for the eigenspaces of $A^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose $A$ is given and I want to find corresponding eigenvalues and bases of eigenspaces of $A^n$. Then I know from $Ax = \lambda x$, $A^n x = A^{n-1} (Ax) = \lambda^n x$, so it seems $A^n$ has eigenvalues $\lambda^n$ and same eigenvector $x$

First, am I right? and second, if this is true, How one can prove this rigorously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right and the formal proof could be written using induction. We want to show that $A^n$ has eigenvalue $\lambda^n$, if $A$ has eigenvalue $\lambda$, and that $A^n$ has the same corresponding eigenvector, say $v$. This is, $A^n v = \lambda ^n v$ for all $n$. Now the case $n = 1$ is evidently true, so assume that the statement is true for a fixed $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then we have 
$$A^{n + 1} v= A (A^n v).$$

Now, by the induction hypothesis, $A^n v = \lambda^n v$. Hence

$$A^{n + 1}v = A(\lambda^n v) = \lambda^n (Av) = \lambda^n (\lambda v) = \lambda^{n + 1} v, $$

which proves the claim.

Comment: This proves that some of the eigenvalues of $A^n$ take the form $\lambda^n$. How do you know that *all* of the eigenvalues of $A^n$ look like this?

Comment: You may write $\lambda_i$ instead of $\lambda$, where $i = 1, \dots, n$.

Comment: This works for diagonalizable matrices — what if you don’t have many eigenvectors?

Comment: @SantanaAfton You don't need the eigenvectors span the whole space. Each distinct eigenvalue of $A$ has at least one eigenvector that is linearly independent from other eigenvectors (but you also don't need that). This is a perfectly fine proof of the statement "if $(\lambda,v)$ is an eigenpair of $A$ then $(\lambda^n,v)$ is an eigenpair of $A^n$". Because the statement starts with "if" so you assume the existence from the beginning.