# Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors for $f(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra

This is somehow related with my previous question [Eigenvalues and bases for the eigenspaces of $A^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3583009/eigenvalues-and-bases-for-the-eigenspaces-of-an)

I noticed $A^n$ and $A$ have the same eigenspace. Suppose $A$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda $ and eigenvector $v$. Naively I can think of $f(A) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_i A^i= a_0 I + a_1 A + \cdots a_n A^n$. Since $A, \cdots, A_n$ have same eigenspace, I think $f(A)$ also have same eigenvector $v$ with eigenvalue $f(\lambda) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_i \lambda^i$.

Am I right? How one can prove or disprove this?

Comment: Be careful when you say "the same". It only goes in one direction: for instance if $f(A)=0$ then all (non-zero) vectors are eigenvectors of $f(A)$, but of course they are not eigenvectors of $A$ in general.

Answer (score 0):

Without restricting the generality, we can suppose the matrix is defined on an algebraically closed field, there exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that $PAP^{-1}$ is upper triangular, $f(PAP^{-1})$ is upper triangular and the diagonal components are $f(a_{ii})$ where $a_{ii}$ is the $(i,i)$-term of $A$ and an eigenvalue, so the result is true.

Comment: If $V$ is an eigenspace of $A$ with eigenvalue $r$, then for all $x\in V$ you have $f(A)(x)=f(r)v$. The example of $f$ the characteristic polynomial is not disproving anything.